# obtain brand name and dept name

Tags: mysql

1st one is brand table which has brand_id and its name. 2nd table is department table which contains dept_id n its name and third table product_details table which has brand_id,dept_id,site_id and site_name.

I want to have brand_name,dept_name and number of sites for particular brand.

I tried this query but its returning brand_id and dept_id instead of brand_name and dept_name since product_details table doesn't contain brand_name and dept_name.

select department_id,brand_id,count(site_id) from product_details group by brand_id;

Answer (score 0):

Join your tables:

```
SELECT   dept_name, brand_name, COUNT(*)
FROM     product_details
    JOIN department USING (dept_id)
    JOIN brand      USING (brand_id)
GROUP BY dept_id, brand_id
```